# Filemaker 12 Pro Video and Audio keep playing on record change

Tags: video, filemaker

I have a container field for interactive content and I added a video , which keeps playing when I go to the next record. Any way to stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the container field. In the inspector under Data tab, go down to Data Formatting, and uncheck the box "start playback automatically".

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the problem. Normal behaviour is for interactive content to pause when you leave the record. Do you have the latest updates (12.0v4)? 12.0v3 had a fix for a similar issue "Addressed an issue where an interactive container would continue playing video or audio after the record it was located on had been deleted."

Answer (score 0):

Using "Show All Records" step on a script button will stop the video.